# jQuery selector problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<input type="radio" id="rad1" name="group" value="one">First Option</input><br>
<input type="radio" id="rad2" name="group" value="two">Second Option</input><br>
<input type="radio" id="rad3" name="group" value="three">Third Option</input><br>

<br>

<input type="radio" id="rad7" name="group2" value="one">First Option</input><br>
<input type="radio" id="rad8" name="group2" value="two">Second Option</input><br>
<input type="radio" id="rad9" name="group2" value="three">Third Option</input><br>
```

The following statements are `true`

```
$('[value="one"]').length == 2

$('[name="group2"]').length == 3
```

So how come..

```
$('[value="one"]',$('[name="group2"]')).length == 0
```

?

I would have thought that this should effectively look within all elements with `name==group2` for elements with `value=="one"` ie `1`. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This selector, using the second argument for scope/context:

```
$('[value="one"]', $('[name="group2"]'))
```

Attempts to find elements with `[value="one"]` that *descend from* elements with `[name="group2"]`. That means you end up looking down at least two levels of different elements in the DOM.

In your case, your radio buttons have both attributes, so you want to attach both attribute selectors instead (I add `input` just to save jQuery some work):

```
$('input[name="group2"][value="one"]')
```

Comment: Yes, this! The first decent explanation

Comment: @Gaby: Is it faster because of the `:radio`? I'm not sure about that. It would seem it would have to analyze all the inputs either way.

Comment: @Gaby: Actually, the `:radio` breaks the validity for `querySelectorAll`, so in many browsers it will be much slower (even than your answer, which I didn't see down there). Sorry @BoltClock.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, that's the bad thing about Sizzle. They have a lot of great extra features, but they make `qsa` useless. In my opinion, a person is better off using only valid selectors (ignoring those other features) then performing additional filters thereafter as needed.

Comment: @patrick: you know a nice source where all non-qsa selectors are mentioned?

Comment: @jAndy: As far as an official source, I don't know of any, though the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) homepage lists *"CSS3 Support"*, then goes on to list a bunch of others, which I'm pretty sure are all non valid CSS selectors. What I usually do for a quick test is just open the console and test it `document.querySelectorAll('input:radio')`. If I get a SYNTAX_ERR, I know it wasn't valid.

Comment: @jAndy: ...one thing a person could do is modify the Sizzle portion of jQuery in their development environment to log a warning to the console when a non-valid selector is used. This should be easy since Sizzle just uses a couple `try/catch` statements to try `qsa`. Log a warning in the `catch`, and you're set.

Comment: @patrick .. *sigh*.. I meant that he answered faster than me and his explanation about the context was better.. But your points are valid regardless. and very interesting as well :) .

Comment: @Gaby: Yeah, I'm supremely adept at missing someone's point. Sorry about that.

Comment: @patrick dw: upvoted your comments regarding `querySelectorAll()` for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is:

```
$('[name="group2"][value="one"]')
```

This selects elements that have a `name` attribute with value `group2` **and** `value` attribute with value `one`.

`$(selector, element)` is something different. It will find all descendants of `element` which match `selector`. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:[value="one"], input:[name="group2"]').length === 5
```

You have to use **one** string, comma separated. BTW it's bad practice to write a selector like `[anything=foobar]`. That is an implicit usage of the **universal selector(*)** which would query all elements in your markup.

This would query both selectors and add the results together in a wrapped set. If you want query for nodes which own both attributes, wire things up like:

```
$('input:[value="one"][name="group2"]').length === 1
```

Comment: This will find every input with `value="one"` or `name="group2"` or both.

Comment: @Downvoter: wow whoever you are, but you really annoy me :p time for an admin call I guess

Answer (score 1):

You want this instead to find value `one` from `group2`:

```
$('input[name="group2"][value="one"]').length
```

This is called the [`multiple-attribute-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

Notice that I also added an `input` tag selector. This is so *every* element on the page doesn't need to be analyzed.

Comment: 'sup mate! was **sup** ! was **sup** !

Comment: What clever people we are with our sups. ;o) If you really want to have fun, nest a sub in a sup. (works on chrome anyway)

Answer (score 0):

try the length of $('[value="one"], [name="group2"]')